# Python3 multiple inheritance: can call all super constructors at one sub constructor?

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

Is it possible in `D's __init__` method, that I can call `A, B, C's __init__`? The following D class only calls `C's __init__`.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a='a'):
        print("Constructor A")
        self.a = a

class B:
    def __init__(self, b='b'):
        print("Constructor B")
        self.b = b

class C:
    def __init__(self, c='c'):
        print("Constructor C")
        self.c = c

class D(C, B, A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        return self.b

d = D()
print(d.run)
```

Comment: Of course, if you want to use `super()` for cooperative multiple inheritance, you need to use `super()` in all the constructors. See [super considered super](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) Otherwise, call them explicitely

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Could you please put your suggestion in code as an answer. I, not being very familiar with oop, would really appreciate to learn how to do this. PS. I am not op :)

Comment: @MuhdMairaj there are many existing questions, and the best thing to do is to read through that link, it is explained by a Python core contributor much better than I can. There's even a PyCon talk versions which is great: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know all of the superclasses, you can call the methods explicitly.

```
class D(C, B, A):
  def __init__(self):
    A.__init__(self)
    B.__init__(self)
    C.__init__(self)
```

We can even automate this using `__mro__` to get all superclasses.

```
class D(C, B, A):
  def __init__(self):
    for cls in self.__class__.__mro__[1:]:
      cls.__init__(self)
```

MRO stands for "method resolution order". It's a list of all of the classes in the inheritance hierarchy for the given class, in the order `super()` would see them. For your class `D`, it's `[D, C, B, A, object]`. We use `[1:]` to eliminate `D` from the list (as calling `D.__init__` would cause infinite recursion).

Comment: some additional reading [here](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html) on MRO from Guido himself for anyone interested in the nerdy side of things...